# Variance of ARMA process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, variance, time-series, stationary-processes, noise

**Problem**
Given $ARMA(1,1)$ stationary process $$x_t = 0.7 x_{t-1} + u_t + 0.2 u_{t-1} $$ where $u_t$ is [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise), with standard deviation $\sigma(u_t) = 4$

Note, stationarity of $x_t$ implies that
$$ \Bbb E(x_t) = const = \mu$$
$$ \Bbb Cov(x_t, x_{t+k}) = \gamma_k$$

Find $ \Bbb Var(x_{t+1}|x_t, u_t)$

**My ideas**
We could substitute the expression of $x_t$ into the variance (I can do that), but I do not really understand what the fact that it is $ARMA(1,1)$ process gives us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the fact that it is $ARMA(1,1)$ process does not change the procedure much.
$$ Var( x_{t+1}| x_y, u_t) = Var(0.7x_t + u_{t+1} + 0.2u_t |x_t, u_t) = Var(u_{t+1}) = 16$$ as $ 0.7x_t$ and $ 0.2u_t$ are considered as constants so disappear from the variance and $u_{t+1}$ is independent of $x_t, u_t$ so it is usual non-conditional variance.